# need help to plot a pandas dataframe with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
name=['name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name3']
date=['2023/01/01', '2023/02/01', '2023/02/01', '2023/03/01', '2023/01/01', '2023/02/01', '2023/01/01', ]
quantity=[5, 3, 15, 10, 5, 15, 10]
site=['site1', 'site1', 'site2', 'site3', 'site1', 'site2', 'site3', ]
df= pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'date': date, 'quantity': quantity, 'site': site})
df

    name    date    quantity    site
0   name1   2023/01/01  5   site1
1   name1   2023/02/01  3   site1
2   name1   2023/02/01  15  site2
3   name1   2023/03/01  10  site3
4   name2   2023/01/01  5   site1
5   name2   2023/02/01  15  site2
6   name3   2023/01/01  10  site3
```

then I do a groupby

```
df.groupby(by=['name', 'date']).agg({'quantity':['sum'], 'site': ['count']})

                    quantity    site
                    sum         count
name    date        
name1   2023/01/01  5           1
        2023/02/01  18          2
        2023/03/01  10          1
name2   2023/01/01  5           1
        2023/02/01  15          1
name3   2023/01/01  10          1
```

Now I would like to plot name with x=date and y=sum and count
in this case I want 3 plots

can someone help me with that ?

Comment: it is not clear, what you want

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
# remove MultiIndex in columns
df1 = df.groupby(by=['name', 'date']).agg({'quantity': 'sum', 'site': 'count'})

# ploting per name groups
df1.groupby('name').plot()
```

Another idea:

```
for name, g in df1.groupby(level='name'):
    g.droplevel(0).rename_axis(None).plot()
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael
it work fine but I see 2 think strange.
on the X axis, I can see name and date as index
and the legende I can see None, None also (and don't know where is it coming from)

Answer (score 0):

You can plot by using the df.plot(), before that you need to reset your index. Your current dataFrame has multiple indexes

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.plot(x='date', y='sum')
```